# adding a div inside another div but at "compile-time", not after the DOM has loaded

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to build a webapplication which will display a number of messages from our organisation.

However I'm struggling a bit with the "template" which I need to build to generate the webpage and the messages that are coming from a database.

Below you'll see the code which I'm trying to generate dynamically:

```
<li id="message2590" class="messageContainer">
  <div class="messageHeader">
    <div class="messageType"><img class="messageTypeIcon" src="images/icon_image.png" width="64px" height="64px"></div>
    <div class="messageId">2590</div>
  </div>
  <div class="messageItem">
    <div class="messageItemHeader">
      <div class="messageAuthor">Name</div>
      <div class="messageValidation">
        <div id="2590" class="validation"></div>
        <div id="2590" class="highlight"></div>
        <div id="2590" class="edit"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2590" class="messageContent image">
      <img id="2590" data-rotation="0" src="myimage.png"><img class="rotate" src="images/btn_rotate.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Below is what I've managed to build:

```
<li id="message2590" class="messageContainer">
  <div class="messageHeader">
    <div class="messageType"><img class="messageTypeIcon" src="images/icon_image.png" width="64px" height="64px"></div>
    <div class="messageId">2590</div>
  </div>
  <div class="messageItem">
    <div class="messageItemHeader">
      <div class="messageAuthor">Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="messageValidation">
      <div id="2590" class="validated"></div>
      <div id="2590" class="highlight"></div>
      <div id="2590" class="edit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2590" class="messageContent image">
  <img id="2590" data-rotation="0" src="myimage.png"><img class="rotate" src="images/btn_rotate.png">
  </div>
</li>
```

So I'm close but there are two blocks that are not in the right div.

The div with class"messageValidation" and it's child-divs needs to be inside "messageItemHeader".

The div with class "messageContent" and it's child-elements needs to be inside "messageItem".

Below you'll find the code which I'm using to generate the HTML:

```
var li = $('<li id="message' + messageId + '" class="messageContainer" />');

                var messageHeader = $('<div class="messageHeader" />');
                messageHeader
                .append($('<div class="messageType" />')
                .append($('<img class="messageTypeIcon" src="images/icon_' + messageType + '.png" width="64px" height="64px" />')))
                .append($('<div class="messageId" />').text(messageId));
                li.append(messageHeader);


        var messageItem = $('<div class="messageItem" />');
                messageItem
                .append($('<div class="messageItemHeader" />')
                .append($('<div class="messageAuthor" />').text(messageUserName)));



                var messageValidation = $('<div class="messageValidation" />');

        // 
                if (messageValidation == 0)
                {
          messageValidation.append($('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="validation" />'));
                }
                else
                {
          messageValidation.append($('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="validated" />'));
                }


                if (messageHighlight == 0)
                {
          messageValidation.append($('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="highlight" />'));
                }
                else
                {
          messageValidation.append($('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="highlighted" />'));
                }

                messageValidation.append($('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="edit" />'));

                messageItem.append(messageValidation);

                li.append(messageItem);

                if (messageType == "text")
        {
          var messageContents = $('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="messageContent text" />').text(messageText);
        }
        else if (messageType == "image")
        {
          var messageContents = $('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="messageContent image">');
          var tempImg = $('<img id="' + messageId + '" data-rotation="' + messageRotation + '" src="' + messageMedia + '" /><img class="rotate" src="images/btn_rotate.png" />');
          tempImg.on('load',function(){ checkRotation() });

          messageContents.append(tempImg);
        }
        else if (messageType == "video")
        {
          var messageContents = $('<div id="' + messageId + '" class="messageContent video" />');
        }



        li.append(messageContents);

        $('#Messages').append(li);
```

I've also added this code to jsFiddle but it doesn't work because there are some booleans in it which ofcourse won't work but you might get an idea.

Does anybody know how I can get those divs inside those other divs?

https://jsfiddle.net/quexck77/

One last thing, because I know I will get remarks about it.... I know I'm not supposed to use the same id multiple times but I'm never going to do anything with it. These id's are only there to serve as a reference when I click on one of those images to be able to retrieve the id in the database.

And those id's are not relevant to the issue which I'm having.

Thanks!
Kenneth

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language like Java or C#, its interpreted by the browser. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your title seems at odds with what you're actually trying to do. Also note that just because you don't use the duplicate `id` attributes doesn't mean they won't interfere with your page. You should remove them. There's better ways to identify elements if that's all you want - classes or data attributes for example

Comment: I'd suggest you place the template within the HTML source that's initially loaded. Then you can simply `clone()` it. This pattern has multiple advantages. Firstly it's *much* simpler, tidier JS code. Secondly, you can update the template at any time just by amending the HTML. Right now, if the template changed you'd have to trudge through the JS which isnt a good separation of concerns. Thirdly, although I haven't tested it, I'd place a bet that cloning will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks Rory for your comment. Do you know where I could find a tutorial for this template as you are expaining?